# SQL Count clarification

Tags: sql, count

Possibly a little off topic, hoping that you might be able to help me solve a bit of an argument.

Story is, I'm working with an 3rd party application which has it's own in built SQL query engine. The developer for this application is 100% convinced that their SQL implementation adheres to all standards. I believe that it doesn't.

Consider the following query:

```
Select Count(*) 
From TableName 
Where id = 1000
```

If there is a record with an id of 1000, I get 1 record in my result set.

However, if there is no record with an id of 1000, I get 0 records in my result set. I believe I should get 1 record with a 0 value but the 3rd party developer says that that is correct.

I have pointed him to this (which he chooses to disregard)
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-function.php

To be honest, I don't know for sure exactly how "official" it is.

Am I right or have I got this wrong?

And of course I realise, the 3rd party developer is quite within his rights to ignore this anyway

Comment: "I believe I should get 1 record with a 0 value but the 3rd party developer says that that is correct" - is he saying it's correct to return a single result with `0` or he's saying it's correct to get an empty (0-rows) result set?

Comment: @Dai, He is saying correct to return empty result set.  Sorry, that could of been a bit more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When evaluating a claim of being correct or standards-compliant we must go to the suitable authority, in this case the SQL-92 specification (which is the simplest and most widely implemented SQL specification and because later specifications do not abrogate SQL-92). Avoid websites that present a watered-down, beginner-friendly, or "real-world" version of a specification when looking for an authoritative source (so your 3rd-party developer is being cautious by ignoring `w3resource.com` or `w3schools.com`, for example).

[The SQL-92 specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) defines `COUNT(*)` under section 6.5. `6.5 <set function specification>` (today these are often instead referred to as "group aggregation functions"). It defines `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, and `COUNT`. We are concerned with `COUNT(*)`, which it defines like so (emphasis mine):

> The argument of `COUNT(*)` and the argument source of a `<general set function>` is a table or a group of a grouped table as specified in Subclause 7.8, "", and Subclause 7.9, "`<query specification>`".
>
> Let `T` be the argument or argument source of a `<set function specification>`.
>
> If `COUNT(*)` is specified, **then the result is the cardinality of `T`**.

In your case:

- The "the argument source" is the `FROM tableName WHERE id = 1000` part of your query, this is `T`.
- As your `T` returns zero results then the cardinality of that result is zero `0`.
- So `COUNT(*)` will return a value of `0` (which is not `NULL` either, i.e. `COUNT(*)` never evaluates to `NULL` btw) so you are correct: you must have exactly 1 result row and not zero rows. So he is wrong.

EDIT: (from Gordon)

I don't usually do this, but the simple way to express this is that an aggregation query with no `group by` *always* returns one.  That is what the standard specifies.